# Django Paginator in view

Tags: python, django, pagination

I have the code for searching and the pagination code in the same View, so whenever i trie to view the second page of the pagination i get the standard search page...
In the django tutorial the list is generated every time the view is called, in my case since the search form is always loaded along with the pagination code the list is wipedout when requesting the second pagination...
What can i do?

Here is the simplified code so you can get the idea:

```
def main_page(request):
anuncios = []


#This is the search 
if request.method == 'POST':
    anuncios = Anuncio.objects.all().order_by('votos').reverse()[0:20]

# Pagination
paginator = Paginator(anuncios, 2)

page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    p_anuncios = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    p_anuncios = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    p_anuncios = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render_to_response('main_page.html', RequestContext(request,
    {'form':form,
    'anuncios': p_anuncios,
    'vazio':vazio
    })
    )
```

Thanks

Comment: anuncios = Anuncio.objects.all().order_by('votos').reverse()[0:20] should be anuncios = Anuncio.objects.all().order_by('-votos')[0:20]

Comment: What if i create a different view and template for pagination an then include it in the search template?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form with some fields that impact the paginator list you can do something like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="current_page" value="{{ anuncios.number }}" />
<input type="submit" name="_next" value="next" />
```

in python

```
page = request.GET.get('current_page','')
if page and page.isdigit() and '_next' in request.GET:
    try:
        p_anuncios = paginator.page(int(page) + 1)
    ...
```

then you can add a hidden input field name="page" with the current page value and vor navigation a next and

Comment: I solved the problem using  'request.session = anuncios', I used it to store the search query, this way its always possible to get the query back for the paginator to work properly.
 [Sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) ... 
Also found help here: 
[Paginating the results of a Django forms POST request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266554/paginating-the-results-of-a-django-forms-post-request)

Comment: Anyway it seams to me that this was not an elegant solution, if someone has any better ideas about this problem, please do tell.
Thanks