# How to store a queryset in django session for pagination

Tags: python, json, django, pagination, django-queryset

In Django 1.6 I've got a model stored in my database which I am querying in order to get a number of results back. However since the results may sometimes be more than enough to fill a page, I am trying to implement the pagination system narrowly following the skeleton of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18106904/178728.

Now the problem that in `request.session` I need to store my queryset and not just plain values. However this creates all sorts of problems as Django complains that my queryset is not json serializable.

So far I've tried doing:

```
1) request.session['data'] = myQueryset # Fails
2) request.session['data'] = serializers.serialize('json', myQueryset) 
   # succeeds at first but fails in deserialization as
   # I can't reassemble the original queryset
```

Anyway my question is this: What's the easiest way to store and then retrieve my queryset?

Note that I need to store the queryset when a user searches the db using a POST request and then retrieve the results through GET for use within the paginator.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why you don`t use this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view?

Comment: @zymud Because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2266950/178728

Comment: @zymud plus the fact that `POST` occurs only the first time a user submits its form which is the only time I can retrieve values through `POST`. Pagination however works through `GET` which means I need to store the user's search somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a solution to my problem: This is exactly what I was looking for: https://gist.github.com/bsnux/4672788

```
import pickle

# Session key
key = 'my_qs'

# Pizza => model example
qs = Pizza.objects.filter(ingredient='tomato')
# Dumping data
request.session[key] = pickle.dumps(qs.query)

# Loading data
pizzas = Pizza.objects.all()[:1]
pizzas.query = pickle.loads(request.session[key])

# Using qs
for pizza in pizzas:
print(pizza.ingredient)
```

Hopefully this helps someone in the future. Cheers.

Comment: Just a side note: It's spread that pickle is not safe and introduce security risks.

Comment: @radev That's true. However in my case all the data come from html `select` boxes which are populated by my database in the first place. Pretty safe I think. Nevertheless, in case you have any alternatives to suggest please feel free to post your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
myQueryset.values()
```

It should return JSON-seralizable queryset.

Comment: If I do this I get a `ValuesQuerySet` which doesn't seem to work.