# Bootstrap for Django form: break down the fields of the form to 3 pages

Tags: django, django-forms, django-bootstrap3

I have a Django form, which has a lot of fields so that I have to break it up to 3 pages. It means user has to fill some fields of the form in one page , and then they click next to go to next pages and continue to fill the forms.

To achieve that, I plan to display some fields of the form on each page.

I have come up with this code:

HTML Page 1:

```
 <form method="POST" action="#" class="form">
     {{form.email}}
     {{form.phone_number}} ...
</form>
```

HTML Page 2 :

```
<form method="POST" action="#" class="form">
    {{form.current_job}}
    {{form.current_salary}}...
</form>
```

It works fine with this code but it just shows the form in basic appearance, I would like to use bootstrap to make it more beautiful.

My questions is that, how can I integrate bootstrap ?

I have come up with this solution, but it is hard-coded and difficult if I changes fields of the form in the future:

```
<label class="control-label" for="id_field1">Field 1</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="id_field1" maxlength="50" name="field1"  type="text"/>

<label class="control-label" for="id_field2">Field 2</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="id_field2" maxlength="50" name="field2"  type="text"/>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paginating the results of a Django forms POST request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266554/paginating-the-results-of-a-django-forms-post-request)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have read that but found no answer for my question. My  question is about how to display only some fields in the form in HTML with the decoration of bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: this answer might be useful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/401025/define-css-class-in-django-forms#answer-20573612
Just add the bootstrap classes you need to your fields