# Paginating without model in django

Tags: sql, django, django-models, pagination

this is my first post ever related to programming therefore please forgive if it is a bit silly.

I'm making a website that will aggregate real estate data from some classified ads websites. I've already managed to write simple scrapers that update the website's database and now I wanted to make the actual web app using Django. 
The website would take data from users that can search the real estate database according to their criteria (already set up a django form and provisionary interface for that.) 
I'm a newbie and don't know a lot about django therefore I've been trying to use a simple function-based-view to process queries and display results based on user's choices. 
I've got completely stuck on pagination - as some queries might have thousands of results it's absolutely essential to implement it but django paginator seems to only be working with a predefined django model.

1. I've tried using django paginator to no avail as it appears to require defined models.
2. I've tried the paginate library but there is no real documentation or examples so I couldn't make it work https://pypi.org/project/paginate/
3. I'm thinking of writing the pagination script by myself but it will take me a very long time probably as it's my first programming project

I would rather keep the code as it is since basically everything works already except for pagination so I simply want to know if there is a simple solution here ie. simple way to include pagination in a python app

Comment: Paginators work fine without a model, they just need something that can be iterated over. But if you're not using a model, where will you store the results of the scrapes between requests?

Comment: @Daniel Roseman Thanks for your answer I will look into it again, are you 100% positive that the default django paginator doesn't require a model to iterate over ?(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/pagination/) I've understood the contrary reading the documentation. I dont quite understand the question however, all the data is pre-scraped for the user and stored in the database before he makes a request - his request is a simple SQL select query that will display data on the webpage. Am I missing something here? (probably yes :D ) Thank you!

Comment: But the very top section on that page you link to shows an example of paginating using a plain list, no model in sight.

Comment: And if the data is stored in the db, why isn't there a model?

Comment: @DanielRoseman thank you so much, i just made some rookie errors elsewhere and wrongly assumed it was a paginator error. I've made paginator work and then got stuck again as it wouldn't let me switch between pages and I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266554/paginating-the-results-of-a-django-forms-post-request       where you also helped!