# django pagination with search not working

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

MultiValueDictKeyError at /search/
'search'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?page=2
Django Version: 4.1.5
Exception Type: MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:
'search'
Exception Location: C:\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py, line 86, in **getitem**
Raised during:  blogs.views.search
Python Executable:  C:\Python311\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.0

views.py

```
def search(request):
    search = request.POST["search"]
    blog_search = Blog.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search) | Q(description__icontains=search))
    paginator = Paginator(blog_search, 5)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    blogs = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    return render(request,"frontend/searchblogs.html",{"blogs":blogs})
```

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-end">
        <form class="form-inline" method="post" action="{%url 'search' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="search" id="search" >
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </nav>
      <h4 class="mt-4"></h4>
      {% for blog in blogs %}
      <div class="card mb-3" >
          <div class="row no-gutters">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="{{blog.cover_img.url}}" alt="..." class="bd-placeholder-img card-img-top img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title text-truncate">{{blog.title}}</h4>
                <p class="card-text text-truncate">{{blog.description}}</p>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                  <p class="text-muted">{{blog.date.date}}</p>
                  <p class="text-muted"><i class="fa fa-eye pl-2"></i>  {{blog.view}}</p>
               </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="{%url 'blogdetail' blog.id %}" class=" stretched-link "></a>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
      <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
        <ul class="pagination justify-content-end">
        {% if blogs.has_previous %}
            <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ blogs.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
          </li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="page-item disabled">
            <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="True">Previous</a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      
        {% if blogs.number|add:'-4' > 1 %}  
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ blogs.number|add:'-5' }}">&hellip;</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      
        {% for i in blogs.paginator.page_range %}
            {% if blogs.number == i %}
                <li class="page-item active" aria-current="page">
              <span class="page-link">
                {{ i }}
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </span>
            </li>
            {% elif i > blogs.number|add:'-5' and i < blogs.number|add:'5' %}
                 <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      
        {% if blogs.paginator.num_pages > blogs.number|add:'4' %}
           <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ blogs.number|add:'5' }}">&hellip;</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      
        {% if blogs.has_next %}
            <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ blogs.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
          </li>
        {% else %}
            <li class="page-item disabled">
            <a class="page-link" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="True">Next</a>
          </li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
      </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `search = request.POST.get("search")`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

views.py

```
def search(request):
    search = request.GET["search"]
    ...
```

You're passing a GET request through the server (the ?page part of the URL), so you'll have to retrieve the data using request.GET['name']. You should also change your form method to GET. For a search, there isn't a good reason to use POST.

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light justify-content-end">
        <form class="form-inline" method="GET" action="{%url 'search' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="search" id="search" >
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </nav>
...
</div>
```

Here's the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects

Form methods: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

If you must use the POST method, refer to this question: [Paginating the results of a Django forms POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266554/paginating-the-results-of-a-django-forms-post-request)